# How can a flash message persist between requests in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A tutorial I am following has the below code which it mentions is not quite right because the error flash persists one request longer than desired because `render` doesn't count as a request. The solution is to use `flash.now` instead.

But how is it even possible for the error flash to persist one extra request? Given that Rails is stateless how is the information of the flash stored for the next request?

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flash is stored in the user's [Session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session), which is associated with them on subsequent requests using HTTP cookies. The flash is just one part of the session whose data is automatically flushed on the next request. See the [Rails Guide to Action Controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Use `flash.now` instead of `flash`.

The flash variable is intended to be used before a redirect, and it persists on the resulting page for one request. This means that if we do not redirect, and instead simply render a page, the flash message will persist for two requests: it appears on the rendered page but is still waiting for a redirect (i.e., a second request), and thus the message will appear again if you click a link.

To avoid this weird behavior, when rendering rather than redirecting we use flash.now instead of flash.